# How to set a field constant in a django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a custom user model and a company model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()
    company = models.ForeignKey(
              Company, null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Company(models.Model):

    company_name = models.CharField(
                   default='', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
```

In `settings.py` I also have a `customer_name` constant:

```
CUSTOMER_NAME = os.environ.get('CUSTOMER_NAME')
```

How can I add a condition in my user model so that if the user `is_staff` boolean is `TRUE` then the `company_name` is fixed to be the `CUSTOMER_NAME` constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have two options:

1) **Option 1**: Overriding save ( [Overriding predefined model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) )

```
from django.conf import settings

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    ...
    company = models.ForeignKey(
          Company, null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_staff:
            #company_name = os.environ.get('CUSTOMER_NAME')
            company_name = settings.CUSTOMER_NAME
            target = Company.objects.get_or_create( company_name = company_name )
            serf.company = target
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

2) **Option 2**: [Using pre-save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders):

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver    
from django.conf import settings

@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    if self.is_staff:
        #company_name = os.environ.get('CUSTOMER_NAME')
        company_name = settings.CUSTOMER_NAME
        target = Company.objects.get_or_create( company_name = company_name )
        serf.company = target
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to do this is to override the save function of your model like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()
    company = models.ForeignKey(
              Company, null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
        if self.instance.id is None and self.is_staff is True:  # instance.id is None indicates the instance is new and not an existing one
            constant_company = Company('company_name'=CUSTOMER_NAME)  # You could also search for an existing company with the CUSTOMER_NAME
            constant_company.save()
            self.company = constant_company

        super().save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

This way will ensure you each time a staff user is saved no matter where a company with your constant name will be linked to it.